# AWS S3API list-objects by Last Modified oldest to newest (AWS CLI)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

How can I get the 20 oldest files in my s3 bucket? I tried doing `aws s3api list-objects --bucket BUCKETNAME --max-items 20 --query "sort_by(Contents,&LastModified).Key" --output text`

However, I get this error: `In function sort_by(), invalid type for value: None, expected one of: ['array'], received: "null"`

Is there a way to do this with a delimiter "/" ?

Comment: Try this instead:
```aws s3api list-objects --bucket bucketname --query 'sort_by(Contents, &LastModified)[-1].Key' --output text```

Comment: Didn't work it only returns 1 item.

Comment: That is good. now try:
aws s3api list-objects --bucket bucketname --query 'sort_by(Contents, &LastModified)[*].Key' --output text